# Where Mono stores xml documentation?

Tags: .net, linux, mono, xml-documentation

By default .Net stores XML documentation generated for each assembly in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5` (on x86 OS for .Net 4.5).

So we can find documenation files like System.xml, System.Core.xml, etc

But where does Mono save such files? I checked Mono's GAC folder which is `/usr/lib/mono/gac` but couldn't find them.

I have locally installed Mono under Ubuntu and also I compiled the latest one, but still couldn't find it. Am I missing some package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the raw xml files are not packaged. Instead, people normally use the monodoc generated from them (install the package `monodoc-manual`).

If you have the mono sources, you can find the xml files scattered in various `Documentation` directories. The full list is in [mcs/docs/Makefile](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/docs/Makefile#L76).

Comment: I was hoped that they are included, but anyway thank you for the answer!